# minimum access to login to a sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint

I am giving full control permission to a document under the shared library to a  user that does not have any permission to the site. Sharepoint 2010 adds limited access to this user to the site itself, I believe so that user can login and see the the document.
However I can not login with this user's credentials.
What is wrong and what is the minimum access level that can be given to a user so that they only login, and see the documents they are supposed see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limited access is a bit confusing because this permission level is only used to allow a user to *traverse* the site in order to access the items on which they have explicit (at least read) permission access. Traverse unfortunately doesn't mean *browse* the site, it's only used to avoid triggering the credentials prompt when accessing the ressource.

If it's just for a specific document, you should link straight to the document, [like Ashutosh Singh suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429047/minimum-access-to-login-to-a-sharepoint-site/4429114#4429114)

Otherwise, if there are no sensitive information, you can add this user in the dedicated visitor group, that will grant him enough access to browse up to the relevant library and access the document.

Another solution is to create a document workspace sub site (with unique permission) and set this user as the owner / contributor. By doing so you'll allow him to have more freedom in his own little shell. While this seems like a big job, it's only a few click away and a few seconds / minutes of configuration if you have enough right on the site collection (which I presume is the case since you are able to give full right to an external user on a specific document).

Hope that helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You would have to provide Viewer rights to the user on document library so that user can open the document library and provide the user direct link to the view which you want to show him.

Second method is what ever rights you have provided is enough for the user just provide him direct link to the document Which would be <>/Documentname.extension
eg. http://sharepointserver:1234/shareddocuments/abc.docx